# When using uri to load a large local image, it is very slow. How can I optimize it?

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I want to implement the function of a local gallery. I first use MediaStore to get the uri of all local pictures, and then display it on the imageView through Picasso / Glide.

If the picture is small, the display speed is fast, but when the picture is large (3mb-4mb or more), the display speed becomes very slow, and the user experience is very bad.

[image: the display speed becomes very slow]

My code is as follows:

```
        // use MediaStore to get the uri of all local pictures
       val cursor = APP.INSTANCE.contentResolver.query(
            EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            arrayOf(_ID, DISPLAY_NAME, DATE_ADDED),
            null,
            null,
            "$DATE_ADDED DESC"
        )
        var images = ArrayList<EImage>()
        while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true) {
            val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID))
            images.add(
                EImage(
                    id = id,
                    name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME)),
                    uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id),
                    added = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DATE_ADDED))
                )
            )
        }


        // Display to imageView via Picasso / Glide
        // Picasso
        Picasso.get().apply {
            isLoggingEnabled = true
        }.load(imageUri).apply {
            config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            resize(400, 400) //
            onlyScaleDown()
            centerInside()
            into(imageView)
        }
        // or Glide
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(imageUri).apply {
            override(400, 400)
            centerInside()
            into(imageView)
        }
```

When the local image is above 3mb-4mb, I found that if the resize width and height are relatively small (below 350), the loading speed is fast, but if the width and height are relatively large (above 350), the loading speed will become Very slow (20-30 seconds per image), I grabbed Picasso's log as follows:

[image: Picasso's log]

May I have done something wrong? How can it be optimized? Thank you very much!